# How to replace the file name(particular specific folder) using Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i can replace the file name in particular folder , i wrote like this

```
FileInfo fsource = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/PurchaseOrder/" + lblhideid.Text));
                        if (fsource.Exists)
                        {
                            string[] file = lblhideid.Text.Split('.');
                            string fName="Z-"+System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")+"-"+saveConsultantID+"."+file[1];
                            fsource.Name.Replace(lblhideid.Text, fName);

                        }
```

lblhideid.Text=image.jpeg , so i can replace the my own name like fName , how to replace the name pls give me any suggestion.

Thank u
Hemanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want that last line to be:

```
fsource.MoveTo(Server.MapPath("~/PuchaseOrder/" + fName));
```

You current code is only getting the filename as a string and manipulate that string.  You want to manipulate the file itself.

EDIT:

Are you sure that `~/PurchaseOrder/` exists?

Try:

```
string originalPath = Server.MapPath("~/PurchaseOrder/" + lblhideid.Text);

FileInfo fsource = new FileInfo(originalPath);
if (fsource.Exists)
{
     string newName = string.Format("Z-{0:MM-dd-yyyy}-{1}.{2}",
                                    System.DateTime.Now,
                                    saveConsultantID,
                                    fsource.Extension);

     string newPath = Path.Combine(fsource.DirectoryName, newName);
     fsource.MoveTo(newPath);                   
}
```

Comment: Could not find a part of the path. is the error pls give me another suggestion

Comment: Are you sure that ~/PurchaseOrder/ exists?  Canyou step through the code a see which part cannot find the path?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, what if they put a filename like file.tar.gz ?

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension("~/PurchaseOrder/" + lblhideid.Text);
string newName = "MYFILE." + extension

File.Move(
    "~/PurchaseOrder/" + lblhideid.Text,
    "~/PurchaseOrder/" + newName );
```